# How to prove this equation I have come across by Induction?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, fake-proofs

I came across this equation in a programming contest(I have simplified it a lot):

> So the problem directly is we are given some constants   < $a_1$ , $a_2$ .. . . . $a_n$ >
>
> and we need to decide the order of   <$x_1$ , $x_2$ ...... , $x_n$ >
>
> such that  $\sum_1^n  a_k * x_k$ (where k varies from 1 to n ) is maximum .
>
> Note we are given both the sets  < $a_1$ , $a_2$ .. . . . $a_n$ >
>    and

So, I have a strong intuition that for the summation to be of maximum value - we should sort both the co efficients in non decreasing order and take the summation of $a_i * x_i$ .

Let the sorted lists be denoted by same set(just for convenience) i.e.

< $a_1$ , $a_2$ .. . . . $a_n$ >  and   <$x_1$ , $x_2$ ...... , $x_n$ >

Now to prove this I was trying to use Induction .

Induction Hypothesis : Let there be i elements in two sets such that their summation of products is maximum when they are sorted in non decreasing order.

Base Case: Tried to prove for < $a_1$ , $a_2$ > and < $x_1$, $x_2$ > and suceeded easily!(Tried all cases assuming $x_1$>$x_2$ and $a_1$>$a_2$ . )

Now , Let the hypothesis be true till n-1

Now , to prove that my hypothesis is true what I was trying is trying to prove:

$a_1$ * $x_1$ + $a_2$ *$x_2$ + . . . . + $a_n-1$ * $x_n-1$ + $a_n$* $x_n$ >= 
$a_1*x_1$ + . . . . . . + $a_k$ *$x_n$ + . . . . $a_n$ * $x_k$

where < $a_1$ , $a_2$ .. . . . $a_n$ > and  are non decreasing

I proved this right but I feel like this is kind of an incomplete proof because I am assuming only two coefficients i.e. $x_n$ and $x_k$ only will be swapped , but more than 2 coefficients can be swapped!

Trying to prove a more general form , I couldn't succeed!
Can you help in proving this via Induction ?
I can be wrong at earlier steps too . But I don't think I am!

Comment: Please see Rearrangement Inequality, for example in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks , for the name of the inequality.
I feel like wikipedia has also swapped 2 co-efficients and tried contradicting that this  permutation is optimal !
Similarly, I have tried something like this only..
So , is my try totally wrong or right ?

Comment: I don't know whether multiple swaps can be dealt with in a similar way. Guess is that likely they can be.